# Can I change the language of UserCreationFrom() html to Spanish?

Tags: django, python-3.x, forms

I've done a register page in my django app for the users to introduce their username and password and register, I wanted to know if I could change the HTML text that the UserCreationForm() shows to spanish.

This is my code so far:

Forms.py

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
     Username = forms.CharField(label = 'Username', max_length = 50)
     password = forms.CharField(label= 'Password', max_length = 50)
```

Views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('login')
else:
    form = UserCreationForm()

context = {
    'form' : form
}
return render(request, 'registration/register.html', context)
```

Urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('registration/', views.register, name='register'),
]
```

register.html

```
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Pagina de Registro</h1>
    <form method= "post" action="{% url 'register' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {% if form.errors %}
        <p>Hay errores en el formulario</p>
        {% endif %}

        {{ form.as_p }}

        <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The HTML page shows this in the browser, I want to change the HTML text to spanish but as the function creates it by itself I was wondering if I could do that.

[image]

Comment: Please include your form code.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

Comment: What Daniel says: Even if you only use Spanish, you should set the language to "es" and Django will automatically use the Spanish version for the default texts. And use `{{ form.as_p }}` (or as_table or as_u) to get a better formatted form.

Comment: I changed the form.as_p and that works but even if I change the language to spanish in the HTML file it still show it in english, I don't know if it is because it doesn't have a translation for the userCreationForm.

Comment: you can replace ```{{ form.as_p}}``` with a custom form and use Spanish instead.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this was ever answered but the way I found to do so is by going to the settings.py file and setting the LANGUAGE_CODE to 'es':

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es'
```

Then I refreshed and it worked fine for me, hope that works.

> language code `es` presents data in Spanish language.

here is the list of [language codes](http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html)